# Having trouble understanding aspects of cardinality.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I am having trouble understanding the meaning of $\omega_\alpha$, I thought it simply meant that it was the initial $\alpha$ segment of $\omega$, but then that wouldnt make sense if $\aleph_0$ is smaller than any other infinite cardinal.

Comment: Do you have a definition of $\omega_\alpha$ you could type into your question? It will be easier to give a helpful answer if we knew how the precise definition you need to understand looks.

Comment: In the notation I am used to, $\omega_1$ is the first uncountable ordinal, so it is definitely not a segment of $\omega$.

Comment: I have the following definitions $\omega_{\alpha +1} = $least cardinal number $ > \omega_\alpha; $ $Lim(\lambda) \rightarrow \omega_\lambda = sup(\omega_\alpha | \alpha < \lambda)$

Comment: Yes, so $\omega_1$ is one step up the "cardinal" ladder from $\omega$, which makes it *many* steps up the ordinal ladder from $\omega$.